# unit testing accuracy of function composition

Tags: unit-testing, f#, function-composition

I'm writing tests for an object that takes in an input, composes some functions together, runs the input through the composed function, and returns the result.

Here's a greatly-simplified set of objects and functions that mirrors my design:

```
type Result =
| Success of string

let internal add5 x = x + 5

let internal mapResult number =
    Success (number.ToString())

type public InteropGuy internal (add, map) = 
    member this.Add5AndMap number =
        number |> (add >> map)

type InteropGuyFactory() =
    member this.CreateInteropGuy () =
        new InteropGuy(add5, mapResult)
```

The class is designed to be used for C# interop which explains the structure, but this problem still can apply to any function under test that composes function parameters.

I'm having trouble finding an elegant way to keep the implementation details of the internal functions from creeping in to the test conditions when testing the composing function, or in other words, isolating one link in the chain instead of inspecting the output once the input is piped entirely through. If I simply inspect the output then tests for each function are going to be dependent on downstream functions working properly, and if the one at the end of the chain stops working, all of the tests will fail. The best I've been able to do is stub out a function to return a certain value, then stub out its downstream function, storing the input of the downstream function and then asserting the stored value is equal to the output of the stubbed function:

```
[<TestClass>]
type InteropGuyTests() = 

    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.``Add5AndMap passes add5 result into map function``() = 

        let add5 _ = 13

        let tempResult = ref 0
        let mapResult result = 
            tempResult := result
            Success "unused result"

        let guy = new InteropGuy(add5, mapResult)

        guy.Add5AndMap 8 |> ignore

        Assert.AreEqual(13, !tempResult)
```

Is there a better way to do this or is this generally how to test composition in isolation? Design comments also appreciated.

Comment: How can you use the `InteropGuy` from your unit test if it's `internal`?

Comment: @MarkSeemann the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. I'm trying to avoid having my assembly publicly expose `FSharpFunc` since it's going to be consumed by C#.

Comment: Don't do that http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/22/unit-testing-internals In essence, by doing that, you're saying that all `internal` code is also `public`, at least when it comes to maintenance.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Please do note that only the constructor is internal. This allows me to construct the type in the assembly and in unit tests but not expose a public constructor that takes in `FSharpFunc`. If I do that it will just confuse my coworkers.

Comment: Seems like above all you doing is testing that function composition really works. Test individual functions separately. When composing them afterwards you can rest assured things will work as expected.

Comment: @Kevin yes, I do have the individual functions under test. I just have a lot of evaluations and I wanted to get some test coverage around the way they were being put together. Granted, it is probable that any problems will be a compilation error but several of these evaluations do have the same signature.

Answer (score 6):

The first question we should ask when encountering something like this is: **why do we want to test this piece of code?**

When the potential System Under Test (SUT) is literally a *single statement*, then which value does the test add?

AFAICT, there's only two ways to test a one-liner.

- Triangulation
- Duplication of implementation

Both are possible, but comes with drawbacks, so I think it's worth asking if such a method/function should be tested at all.

Still, assuming that you want to test the function, e.g. to prevent regressions, you can use either of these options.

## Triangulation

With triangulation, you simply throw enough example values at the SUT to demonstrate that it works as the black box it's supposed to be:

```
open Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Theory>]
[<InlineData(0, "5")>]
[<InlineData(1, "6")>]
[<InlineData(42, "47")>]
[<InlineData(1337, "1342")>]
let ``Add5AndMap returns expected result`` (number : int, expected : string) =
    let actual = InteropGuyFactory().CreateInteropGuy().Add5AndMap number
    Success expected =! actual
```

The advantage of this example is that it treats the SUT as a black box, but the disadvantage is that it doesn't demonstrate that the SUT is a result of any particular composition.

## Duplication of implementation

You can use Property-Based Testing to demonstrate (or, at least make very likely) that the SUT is composed of the desired functions, but it requires duplicating the implementation.

Since the functions are assumed to be referentially transparent, you can simply throw enough example values at both the composition and the SUT, and verify that they return the same value:

```
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Property>]
let ``Add5AndMap returns composed result`` (number : int) =
    let actual = InteropGuyFactory().CreateInteropGuy().Add5AndMap number

    let expected = number |> add5 |> mapResult
    expected =! actual
```

Is it ever interesting to duplicate the implementation in the test?

Often, it's not, but if the purpose of the test is to prevent regressions, it may be worthwhile as a sort of double-entry bookkeeping.

Comment: Say I were to make the constructor public and inject functions as constructor parameters. This would be analogous to providing functions as function parameters in F#-only code. In my real-life app, the functions are injected via the constructor and the method parameters are .NET instances and primitives that I close over using the functions provided to the ctor  and then compose into a larger evaluation. Even if my design may be a bit suspect, it does reflect the use case of functions that take in other functions and compose them, which I believe brings up the same issues. Thoughts?

Comment: @moarboilerplate That sounds reasonable enough to me. You may see something similar in my [Test-Driven Development with F#](http://bit.ly/1Hhru7l) Pluralsight course, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes--I took the course :) I have difficulty using TDD when functions are passed as parameters, and then combined and reduced to another function, esp. when I need to defer evaluation and create closures instead of invoking the functions. When wireup is more complex than `bind a >> map b` I know testing is required but I struggle with being able to isolate the functions without resorting to making a stub method have some side effect. For example I found a bug where I composed a function from a list of functions using `reduce` instead of `reduceBack` and I should have had tests for that.